# Maxlength and Minlength ignored for input type=“number”

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, web-deployment

The maxlength attribute is not working with

```
<input type="number" maxlength="5" maxlength="10" />
```

Answer (score 7):

HTML input type number does not have `maxlength` and `minlength` attribute, instead it has `min` and `max` attribute, you can use `min` and `max` to length of input.

For eg.  for maxlength 2 and minlength 0, you can use `min` and `max` like this-

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="99" />
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason for lack of maxlength and minlength attribute in input type="number"?

Comment: because those attributes doesn't make sense with input type number.